# How do I get the "Next available number" from an SQL Server? (Not an Identity column)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Technologies: SQL Server 2008

So I've tried a few options that I've found on SO, but nothing really provided me with a definitive answer.

I have a table with two columns, (Transaction ID, GroupID) where neither has unique values. For example:

```
TransID | GroupID
-----------------
23      | 4001
99      | 4001
63      | 4001
123     | 4001   
77      | 2113
2645    | 2113
123     | 2113
99      | 2113
```

Originally, the groupID was just chosen at random by the user, but now we're automating it. Thing is, we're keeping the existing DB without any changes to the existing data(too much work, for too little gain)

Is there a way to query "GroupID" on table "GroupTransactions" for the next available value of GroupID > 2000?

Comment: Does it has to be correct under concurrency? If two requests ask for the next GroupID, is it OK if both get the same value or should the returned value also be 'reserved' so no other requests can get the same value?

Comment: There is only 2 users that use this app, so I'm not worried about concurrency.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think from the question you're after the next available, although that may not be the same as max+1 right? - In that case:

Start with a list of integers, and look for those that aren't there in the groupid column, for example:

```
;WITH CTE_Numbers AS (
    SELECT n = 2001
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n + 1 FROM CTE_Numbers WHERE n < 4000 
)
SELECT top 1 n 
FROM CTE_Numbers num
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyTable tab WHERE num.n = tab.groupid)
ORDER BY n
```

Note: you need to tweak the `2001/4000` values int the CTE to allow for the range you want. I assumed the name of your table to by `MyTable`

Comment: This seems to be the correct solution, however, I checked re-wrote `SELECT top 1 n FROM CTE_Numbers num` as `SELECT n FROM CTE_Numbers num` since I wasn't getting my expected answer, and it only came up with the next 100 values. So, from your example, 2001-2101. **EDIT**: Ok, got it working. My only concern is, what if all the values from 2001-2101 are taken? Does it get the next 100 values after 2101?

Comment: You're hitting the MAXRECURSION default limit on the CTE numbers list. You can control this via the MAXRECUSION query hint. See the section on this on this link for more. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx. I would suggest using the 0 option to remove the limit, then control the end point (4000) by setting it to the max groupid in MyTable + 1, that way the range will always have an availble ID in it.

Comment: And problem solved. I've never had to use this kind of query before, but now that I know it, I have a feeling I'll be using it more often. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @Christian: If you're used to the good old fashioned SQL 2000 way of querying then there are a few things to look into that will make life much easier: CTE tables (as used here), CROSS APPLY, PIVOT/UNPIVOT, OVER/PARTITION BY and more.

Answer (score 4):

```
select max(groupid) + 1 from GroupTransactions
```

Comment: you need to ensure groupID > 2000

Comment: obviously, given his data, it would be >2000 anyway, but I'm not sure why he said that...

Comment: Based on what he's given us, the > 2000 req seemed redundant

Comment: The reason for the >2000 is that the current DB has values all over the place. They were chosen at random by users prior to the upgrade. Max(groupid) spits back a value in the billions because of the users poor choice of numbering. Which is why "next Available greater than 2000" makes much more sense.

Comment: So you want to fill in the gaps?  I think that is unclear in your question, you might want to edit to clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

The following will find the next gap above 2000:

```
SELECT MIN(t.GroupID)+1 AS NextID
FROM GroupTransactions t (updlock)
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT NULL FROM GroupTransactions n WHERE n.GroupID=t.GroupID+1 AND n.GroupID>2000)
AND t.GroupID>2000
```

Answer (score 0):

There are always many ways to do everything. I resolved this problem by doing like this:

```
declare @i int = null 

declare @t table (i int)
insert into @t values (1)
insert into @t values (2)
--insert into @t values (3)
--insert into @t values (4)
insert into @t values (5)
--insert into @t values (6)

--get the first missing number
select   @i = min(RowNumber)
from (
select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY i) AS RowNumber, i
    from (
        --select distinct in case a number is in there multiple times
        select distinct i
        from @t
        --start after 0 in case there are negative or 0 number
        where i > 0
    ) as a
) as b 
where RowNumber <> i

--if there are no missing numbers or no records, get the max record
if @i is null
    begin
    select @i = isnull(max(i),0) + 1 from @t
    end

select @i
```

Answer (score 0):

In my situation I have a system to generate message numbers or a file/case/reservation number sequentially from 1 every year.  But in some situations a number does not get use (user was testing/practicing or whatever reason) and the number was deleted.

You can use a where clause to filter by year if all entries are in the same table, and make it dynamic (my example is hardcoded).  if you archive your yearly data then not needed.  The sub-query part for mID and mID2 must be identical.

The "union 0 as seq " for mID is there in case your table is empty; this is the base seed number. It can be anything ex: 3000000 or {prefix}0000. The field is an integer. If you omit " Union 0 as seq " it will not work on an empty table or when you have a table missing ID 1 it will given you the next ID ( if the first number is 4 the value returned will be 5).

This query is very quick - hint: the field must be indexed; it was tested on a table of 100,000+ rows. I found that using a domain aggregate get slower as the table increases in size.

If you remove the "top 1" you will get a list of 'next numbers' but not all the missing numbers in a sequence; ie if you have 1 2 4 7 the result will be 3 5 8.

```
set @newID = select top 1 mID.seq + 1 as seq  from  
(select a.[msg_number] as seq from [tblMSG] a --where a.[msg_date] between '2023-01-01' and '2023-12-31'  
 union select 0 as seq ) as mID  
left outer join  
(Select b.[msg_number] as seq from [tblMSG] b --where b.[msg_date] between '2023-01-01' and '2023-12-31'  
) as mID2 on mID.seq + 1  = mID2.seq where mID2.seq is null order by mID.seq  

-- Next: a statement to insert a row with @newID immediately in tblMSG (in a transaction block).  
--   Then the row can be updated by your app.
```