# Select values not in a certain range in a table

Tags: sql

I have a table with an id column and hundreds of thousands of rows. I have been given a list of 1000 IDs to check other table data against. **The IDs are not stored in order. The list of IDs is not in order either.** When I select the table data using those ids only 990 results are returned, meaning since that list was produce, 10 of the results have changed/been removed. How can I find the 10 missing values from that range of data? This is what I'm doing at the moment:

```
select * from mytable
where theId in (100, 2223, 31, 43321...92199, 14000)
```

Returns the 990 results. Can I do something like:

```
select val from (1, 2, 3, 4...999, 1000) 
where val not in (
select * from mytable
where theId in (1, 2, 3, 4...999, 1000)
)
```

EDIT: Sorry for the confusion. I should have mentioned that the ID's aren't in any particular order and I was just using the number 1000 as an example. They're in a random order and the 1000 is just a selection from a much larger table (100,000s of rows).

Comment: Following the edit, I'm actually a bit **more** confused! If there are 1,000 IDs in your list and only 990 are found in the database, then surely you have been given 10 'bad' IDs and the 10 'missing' records simply don't exist?

Comment: Exactly. But I want to find out what those missing IDs are. Because they were at some point there and are now missing.

Comment: But surely they could be *any* of the other 99,000-odd records? When were they there? If someone's deleted 10 records, then I'd say check your backups and transaction logs because you can't `SELECT` missing records!

Comment: Yeah I understand that. If I've got 1000 ids originally, and now searching for all records with those ids returns 10 less, then that means 10 are missing from within that range. The other 990,000 or so records aren't affected because their IDs aren't any one of the 1000 given to me. I'm going down the route of putting those 1000 IDs into another table to compare against. Can't think of a simpler solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There might be case like there is no any record for those missing ids or it might be have some other id like less than 1 or greater than 1000. If table have 1000 records and you got only 990 records in your query then definately missing records have id which is less than 1 or greater than 1000. So those missing records will be come in following query :

```
select val from mytable where 
val not in ( select distinct theId from mytable where theId in (1, 2, 3, 4...999, 1000))
```

**UPDATE :**

For random ids, you can do like :

```
create table #temp (id int)
insert into #temp values
(501),
(1),
(21),
......
....
(4350)

SELECT t.id
FROM #temp t
LEFT OUTER JOIN mytable mt on t.id = mt.device_id
WHERE mt.id IS NULL

drop table #temp
```

Comment: There's 100,00s of other rows that I don't want to search through. I only want to search within the 1000 IDs given to me.

Comment: @edwardmlyte : So you can add condition like val >= 1 and val <= 1000. Still if you get 990 records then it means you have only 990 records between 1 to 1000.

Comment: The IDs aren't in order and aren't necessarily between 1 and 1000. I was more trying to get across that was wanting to search within  a range of 1000 value from a much larger table.

Comment: Yeah thats the sort of thing I want.

Comment: @edwardmlyte : You don't need to write insert into statement every time. You can insert multiple values as like in my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like this:

```
WITH cte AS
(
SELECT 1 x
UNION ALL
SELECT x + 1
FROM cte
WHERE x < 1000
)

SELECT cte.x
FROM cte
LEFT OUTER JOIN myTable s on cte.x = s.theId
WHERE s.theId IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a temporary table and put the 1000 ID's in it?  Then you use the logic you suggested - kind of like this:

```
create table ids (id integer not null);

insert into ids values (1);
insert into ids values (2);
...
insert into ids values (1000);

select id from ids where not exists (select 1 from mytable where theID = ids.id);

drop table ids;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you really get the 1000 records? And if its a range you might try it with this where statement...

```
WHERE theId >= 1 AND theId <= 1000
```

Otherwhise you might use this query to exclude the "found" once...

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE theId NOT IN (
  select theId 
  from mytable 
  where theId is in (1, 2, 3, 4...999, 1000) 
)
```

Comment: Using `BETWEEN 1 AND 1000` is much cleaner

Comment: hypercrypt you are right but i didn't know without asking google wether between is part of ansi-92 sql standart or not... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find IDs that are **NOT** in your list, then:

```
select * from mytable
where theId not in (1, 2, 3, 4...999, 1000)
```

As an aside, if your (integer) IDs really do run from 1-1000 without gaps, you can use

```
BETWEEN 1 AND 1000
```

Comment: The table has 100,000s of rows. The 1000 rows I want are from a list given to me by someone else, so I'm searching for these 1000 values (which aren't necessarily 1 - 1000) and which 10 are missing from within this range.

Answer (score 0):

you can shoot

```
select val 
from my_table
order by val
```

If you are on oracle you can:

```
select val, lead(val) over (order by val) - val as diff_from_next
from mytable
order by val
```

and the column diff_from next will be different form its neighbours.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I gave to the following question should help - you use a CTE to get a list of IDs and compare that to the IDs in the table:

[How do I get the "Next available number" from an SQL Server? (Not an Identity column)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754667/how-do-i-get-the-next-available-number-from-an-sql-server-not-an-identity-col/6754754#6754754)

Answer (score 0):

Written for mssql 2005

```
declare @mytabel table(id int)

-- filling @mytable with 990 values (testdata)
;with a as(
select 1 b
union all
select b + 1 from a
where b < 990
)
insert @mytabel(id)
select b from a
option (maxrecursion 0)

--find the values missing in @mytable
;with a as(
select 1 b
union all
select b + 1 from a
where b < 1000
)
select b from a 
left join @mytabel m 
on m.id = a.b
where m.id is null
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: I should've mentioned that the IDs aren't between 1 and 1000. That was an example. It just 1000 rows selected from a table, which (due to some data updates/changes recently) only returns 990 rows. I just want to find which 10 rows are missing. The whole table is actually 100,000s of rows and this 1000 is just a tiny selection.

Comment: @edwardmlyte you can change the 1000 to the number you need. The top part is just populating data for test purposes. Since you are looking for all the "holes" in the id's this is the best solution for your senario. If you only needed the first "hole" the query would be alot different. You could also replace the 1000 with max value from yourtable