# SQL Server SQL Get list of unused ids

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that ranges from 1-100000 but there are gaps in the ids where items have been deleted. I want a SQL statement that will return me a list of all unused ids in the table so I can get a list of items that were deleted.

I want the list but randomizing the list is a bonus actually. I think it can be done with a rand function...

I'd like to keep it ansi SQL if possible to maintain portability but if not, then that's ok...

Comment: This sounds more like a to do than a question; what is the actual problem? What do you have at the moment?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select values not in a certain range in a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648099/select-values-not-in-a-certain-range-in-a-table)

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for.  http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2012/solving-gaps-and-islands-enhanced-window-functions

Comment: I can find plenty of queries to identify the start of a gap but I want the result set to have all ids in the gap.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a use of Tally Table.

Create our sample data.

```
CREATE TABLE #ids(
    id  INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT #ids ON 
--Insert 100,000 rows 
INSERT INTO #ids(id)
SELECT TOP 100000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
FROM sys.columns a 
CROSS JOIN sys.columns b

SET IDENTITY_INSERT #ids OFF;
-- Randomly delete 1000 rows
WITH cte AS(
    SELECT TOP 1000 id
    FROM #ids
    ORDER BY NEWID()
)
DELETE FROM cte
```

Using a Tally Table, create a list of numbers from 1 - 100,000. Then use `NOT EXISTS` to get the unused `id`s. To randomize the list, add on `ORDER BY NEWID()` clause.

```
DECLARE @min INT = 1,
        @max INT = 100000

;WITH E1(N) AS(
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
),
E2(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E1 a CROSS JOIN E1 b),
E4(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E2 a CROSS JOIN E2 b),
E8(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E4 a CROSS JOIN E4 b),
Tally(N) AS(
    SELECT TOP(@max) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E8
)
SELECT N
FROM Tally t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM #ids WHERE id = t.N
)
ORDER BY NEWID() -- Sorts the result in a random order
```

Comment: You should get appreciation on this full sample